# How to set the TimePickerDialog to current Time and show only the current and future times and not the previous times?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I am a newbie to Android. I am trying to work on the `TimePickerDialog`. I have implemented it and it is working fine, but the only problem is that it is displaying the previous time. Is there any way to show only the current and future time in the TimepickerDialog? I have done the following coding, please guide me.

```
  TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;

        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(Take_Away.this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker,
                            int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

                        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();

                        time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);

                        time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "hh:mm a");
                        et_time.setText(format.format(time.getTime()));
                        hour = selectedHour;
                        minute = selectedMinute;
                    }
                }, hour, minute, false);// Yes 24 hour time
        mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
        mTimePicker.show();
```

Comment: What exactly do you want when timepicker is clicked??

Comment: the timepicker should show the current time and the following future times should only be visible..I dun want the previous times to be shown in the dialog

Comment: @Ann You use setMinDate() function. It sets the minimal date. FYI refer my answer. Hope it will helps you

Comment: You need to set current hour and minute to `setMinValue()`

Answer (score 1):

Pass the current date's *hour* and *time* values when you construct the `TimePickerDialog`.

```
// Get current system time
Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();

mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(Take_Away.this,
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker,
                    int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

                Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();

                time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);

                time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "hh:mm a");
                et_time.setText(format.format(time.getTime()));
                hour = selectedHour;
                minute = selectedMinute;
            }
        },

        currentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), // Current hour value
        currentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE), // Current minute value
        DateFormat.is24HourFormat()); // Check 24 Hour or AM/PM format

mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
mTimePicker.show();
```

Notice the use of `DateFormat.is24HourFormat()` as well. This respects your user's system wide preference for a 24-hour or AM/PM time format.

Comment: What time are you seeing when time picker opens?

Comment: the current time is 12:52 PM...Then I can see 11:52 at the top and 1:54 below

Comment: want I want to do is prevent the scrolling from 12 to 11 and below

Comment: Ah, I get it now. That's not possible unless you create a custom number picker dialog. The number picker has methods like `setMinValue()`, `setMaxValue()`.

Comment: u can provide any links to dat?

Answer (score 1):

Use setMinDate() function. It sets the minimal date in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 in getDefault() time zone. Set the minimum date to today's date, so user won't be able to go past it. Something like following in onCreateDialog:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePickerDialog d = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, year, month, day);  
DatePicker dp = d.getDatePicker(); 
dp.setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
return d;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below. Hope it will help you

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;

            // Show selected date
            editOutputDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));

        }`
    };
```

```
private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
```

Comment: Question's about date not time

Answer (score 0):

Think this will help
mTimePicker.updateTime(hourOfDay,minute);